# i think my application is not reading hibernate configuration file

Tags: hibernate

it is not reading the annotated class and it is not reading drop and recreate database schema while startup property also instead of these when i hard code the statements like,

```
config.addAnnotatedClass(UserDetail.class); this is for making annotation class visible to my application and

new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true); this is for recreate database schema while startup property.
```

above two statements is working fine but with out these two statements we can make them read via config file even though i made it, it is not reading. why?

here goes my config file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <!--  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">TESTSCHEMA</property> -->

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup --> 
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- name of the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="com.hibernate.CollectionDemo.UserDetail"/>

        <!--<mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Person.hbm.xml"/>

    -->
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

and there is small warning in this config file it says "The resource is a duplicate of src/hibernate.cfg.xml and was not copied to the output folder" does this mean any? if other please specify,
here comes main class,

```
package com.hibernate.CollectionDemo;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;


public class TestUserDetail 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    UserDetail usrd=new UserDetail();

    Configuration config=new Configuration();
    config.addAnnotatedClass(UserDetail.class);
            config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);

            SessionFactory sf=config.buildSessionFactory();

            Session s=sf.openSession();
            s.beginTransaction();

            usrd.setUserName("FirstUser");

            Address addr=new Address();
            addr.setCity("CN");
            addr.setPincode("16345");
            addr.setState("TN");
            addr.setStreetName("t-nagar");

            Address addr2=new Address();
            addr2.setCity("hyd");
            addr2.setPincode("5845");
            addr2.setState("AP");
            addr2.setStreetName("pet");

            usrd.getListOfAddress().add(addr);
            usrd.getListOfAddress().add(addr2);

            s.save(usrd);
            s.getTransaction().commit();

}
}
```

Comment: Don't think check it. Coding is binary or it does or not. There is no place for assumption.

Comment: yes i even tried what i said above. and i mentioned it also.

Comment: What is name of the configuration file and how are you initializing it  , share the code.

Comment: name is hibernate.cfg.xml, and i already shared config file here.  
just not updated with main class.

Comment: new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true); does not create a new Database schema, it does an export of your current one, and the parameters are (LOG_TO_CONSOLE, EXPORT_THE_SCRIPT_TO_THE_DATABASE).

Comment: with the statement "new SchemaExport(config).create(true,true)" in our main class acts same as the element in the hibernate.cfg.xml named  "<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->" which i experimented practically. so instead of configuring in xml file I hard coded in the main class, and related to my problem i donno after a few trials i got succeded and my application went right. executed correctly.

Comment: Did you use both together?, cuz i havent seen that behavior by just calling the create function... look at the documentation:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html